# Displaying each item in a JS Array separately

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get Javascript Array to display each group name and group ID on its own line instead of sending the whole array to the next script. Essentially what would be desired is that the group ID and Group Name gets pushed "foreach" to the next script that will use those ids to generate a tab. I have the tab generation done and the data import done, the only thing I cant figure out is how to get the array to display each item separately.

Here is my current code:

```
$.getJSON("inc/load.php", function(data){
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {

var Names = data.group_name[i];
var GroupID = data.group_id[i];

    console.log(Names + "  " + GroupID)


}
```

I have searched on here and google and have not found a solution.

**EDIT**

The data does load information correctly, when you use 
`console.log(data[i]);` it returns this style information in the console log:

```
Object {group_id: "556336557801913", group_name: "How to Start a Startup"}
Object {group_id: "1448816275428542", group_name: "ARK: Survival Evolved"}
Object {group_id: "286255764917755", group_name: "VIP BUYER ADVANTAGE MEMBER"}
```

What I would like the end result to be is to take the Group_Id and the Group_name put each into its own variable and then pass those variables to another function. And then repeat for the next item in the array.

Im sorry I am still new to Stackoverflow and learning how to best construct my questions.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide a sample of data.

Comment: How are you displaying the items now? Are you calling another function to do so? Is that what you mean by "the next script"? As shown, we have no idea *what* the end result is supposed to look like, where it should go, etc.

Comment: Is the array valid? Aka did the JSON.parse(data) give back a valid array of objects? And what do you mean with 'display each item seperately' if you want to send the result to the new function?

Comment: I added more information. Thank you for the help

Comment: Ya there is an Add Tab Function that takes the Name and Group Id and creates a new tab with that information

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Rather than using for-in as Paul Rob rightly pointed out, you might just correct the following in your code for a start and that might sort you out.

```
var Names = data[i].group_name;
var GroupID = data[i].group_id;
```

**End Edit**

I think what you want is:

```
for (var i in data) {
  var Names = data[i].group_name;
  var GroupID = data[i].group_id;
  console.log(Names + "  " + GroupID);
}
```

Don't ask me why i is the index rather than the item, one of those nuances of javascript you just grow to live with and love :)

Comment: I disagree slightly @PaulRoub but I'll just edit my answer instead

Comment: That displays object object on the console log and when I try to pass it it shows an error

Comment: It seems you may not be getting what you expect in your data object. Try doing console.log(JSON.stringify(Names)); and console.log(JSON.stringify(GroupID) to see what type of objects they are. Or you could just use chrome developer tools or firebug and set a break point before the console.log statement and then you can inspect your data properly